# Photoshop on wine becomes freezing when I using the tools

Tags: 16.04, wine, photoshop

I installed Adobe photoshop cs6 via on Ubuntu 16.04 via wine. And it's open normally, as for open a photoshop tools, the program becomes freezing until restart it by quit force or killing processes.
What's the solution please?

Comment: Did you check the Wine database site?

Comment: Last I checked a few weeks ago, It wasn't supported. I'm honestly surprised you even got it to run. Maybe you should try [PlayOnLinux](https://www.playonlinux.com/en/).

Comment: I have it running fine,  installing with Playonlinux

Answer (score 0):

When I use photoshop via wine sometimes it seems to freeze, but if I press twice the super key it solves the issue.
In fact it happens when I put the mouse on a button for a while or when I change the zoom.  I don't know why it happens.